# Hex string output different in browser and server javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to wrap a series of chars by hex strings, with this little script:

```
var resultBuffer = [];
var sourceBuffer = "004CS01".split('');

resultBuffer.push("\\x" + "02");

for (var i = 0; i < sourceBuffer.length; i++) {
    resultBuffer.push(sourceBuffer[i]);
}

resultBuffer.push("\\x" + "03");
resultBuffer.push("\\x" + "62");
console.log(resultBuffer);
```

I am facing a problem where one and the same script creates different output. This is from browser: Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m5sUD/

```
["\x02", "0", "0", "4", "C", "S", "0", "1", "\x03", "\x62"]
```

And this from nodejs server (see http://runnable.com/me/U1NzLLgIj8pXRQq4 ):

```
[ '\\x02', '0', '0', '4', 'C', 'S', '0', '1', '\\x03', '\\x62' ]
```

Why is it different? I need the output on the server to be just like in the browser.

Comment: @AmitJoki how is it broken?

Comment: The runnable.com link doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

resultBuffer values of browser and node.js are same. If you print each value in resultBuffer, node.js and browser print same value.

try below code

```
for (idx in resultBuffer) console.log(resultBuffer[idx]);
```

in my pc, node.js and browser print same below values.

```
\x02
0
0
4
C
S
0
1
\x03
\x62
```

it's a just matter of representation method of array values in node.js and browser. values are same.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is due to fact that `\` is not a special character in browser javascript, while it is a special character in `node.js` and hence it is escaped by another backslash `\`

Comment: Any solution to this problem?

Comment: @artworkadシ, I don't know. My answer was just a guess. I actually don't know node.js. Sorry :(

Comment: _"\ is not a special character in browser javascript"_ - The backslash is the escape character in JavaScript strings, whether in the browser or in node.js. What do you mean "not a special character"?